# Adding a text link under the post title in the lists of posts

Tags: posts, admin, links

I made a lot of changes to my WP settings and now, when I approve and publish pending posts,  authors have one hour to modify their articles.
After the hour has gone the edit link disappear and they can't change anymore.
I need to give them the opportunity to remove the post but the "trash" link has gone either.
I've been thinking about adding a new text link under the post title to let the authors send me a message asking to delete the post.
The text link should have the name of the post as subject in order to understand wich post need to be removed.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Add a link under the post title in backend, in single edit view or table list of posts or in frontend under the post title?

Comment: I meant that I need this code in the backend, in the page with the list of posts under the title of each post, nexxt to the "View" link...

Answer (score 4):

You can enhance, change the strings to each post title in the table view of backend on post via hook:

`add_filter( 'post_row_actions', array( $this, 'add_archive_link' ), 10, 2 );`

See the result in this screenshot:

[image]

Below you find my method to add a link

```
    /**
     * Add link on archive
     *
     * @uses   get_post_type_object, get_archive_post_link, current_user_can, esc_attr
     * @access public
     * @since  0.0.1
     * @param  array string $actions
     * @param  integer $id
     * @return array $actions
     */
    public function add_archive_link( $actions, $id ) {
        global $post, $current_screen, $mode;

        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

        if ( is_array( $this->def_archive_screens ) && ! in_array( $current_screen->id, $this->def_archive_screens ) )
            return $actions;
        if ( ! current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) )
            return $actions;

        $actions['archive'] = '<a href="' . $this->get_archive_post_link( $post->ID ) 
            . '" title="'
            . esc_attr( __( 'Move this item to the Archive', $this->textdomain  ) ) 
            . '">' . __( 'Archive', $this->textdomain  ) . '</a>';

        return $actions;
    }
```

You must use the hook `admin_action_{your_string}` for the callback, if the user click on the link. Also below a example for my string `archive`:

```
    add_action( 'admin_action_archive', array( $this, 'archive_post_type' ) );
```

Now the method for the hook:

```
    /**
     * Archive post type
     *
     * @uses   wp_die, set_post_type, add_post_meta, wp_redirect, admin_url
     * @access public
     * @since  0.0.1
     * @return void
     */
    public function archive_post_type () {

        if ( ! (
            isset( $_GET['post']) || 
            ( isset( $_REQUEST['action']) && 'archive' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) 
        ) ) {
            wp_die( __( 'No post to archive has been supplied!', $this->textdomain ) );
        }

        $id = (int) ( isset( $_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : $_REQUEST['post']);

        if ( $id ) {
            $redirect_post_type = '';
            $archived_post_type = get_post_type( $id );
            if ( ! empty( $archived_post_type ) )
                $redirect_post_type = 'post_type=' . $archived_post_type . '&';
            // change post type
            set_post_type( $id, $this->post_type_1 );
            // add old post_type to post meta
            add_post_meta( $id, $this->post_meta_key, $archived_post_type, TRUE );
            wp_redirect( admin_url( 'edit.php?' . $redirect_post_type . 'archived=1&ids=' . $id ) );
            exit;
        } else {
            wp_die( __( 'Sorry, i cant find the post-id', $this->textdomain ) );
        }

    }
```

You find a plugin, there use this on [github](https://github.com/bueltge/Archive/blob/master/archive.php).

Comment: This code doesn't seem to simply add a text link as I asked...

Comment: Why, maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to repost it...
For every contributor (my default role for subscribers) I need to add a text link under the title of any published post in their backend.
The text must be "ask for removal of title_of_the_post) and the link should open their emal account with the subject already filled (example: Mysite.com - Remove title_of_the_post).
Hope I did clarify, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a link below the title in the list of all posts, there remove the title of the current post? Your contibutors (role) can remove the title. I don't understand the goal. What do it, if the user click this and remove the title? Can he change this or will you change the status of this current post to draft, or other status?

Comment: I don't want my contributors to edit their post when it's already published, I've added a function to disable editing and deleting but I still want to give them the chance to delete by clicking on a button available in the author.php page (this one is already active).
The link text requested should bring to this page...

Comment: Always a question to clarify: You like a link below the title of posts in the list-posts screen. The link bring the user to his author.php page inside the backend?

Comment: Nope... It brings to their author.php in the frontend...

Comment: OK, but a link to other page. Can you not add the string, how in my example of the answer and add the link to this string, that the users can jump to the page.